# open url from pythonanywhere

Tags: python, urllib2, pythonanywhere

This code works well on my local machine, but when I upload and run it on pythonanywhere.com it gives me this error.

My Code:

```
url = "http://www.codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
         req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
         opener = urllib2.build_opener()
         openedReq = opener.open(req, timeout=300)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/GehadAbdallah/main.py", line 135, in openApi
    openedReq = opener.open(req, timeout=300)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

P.S. i'm working on python 2.7

Comment: Can't you read the error? Its a 403 forbidden. Pythonanywhere.com stops any outgoing connections. (maybe only http ones but still)

Comment: @Ronnie and what should I do to enable the outgoing connections ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know their policy. contact them and ask them to enable. firewall is blocking you, without that, you can't. and look, this type of question is not an appropriate programming problem. We don't care/know about your target machine and you even don't know the target machine.

Comment: okay, sorry for disturbance.

Comment: check the faqs before posting please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Free accounts on PythonAnywhere are restricted to a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) of sites, http/https only, and access goes via a proxy.  There's more info here:

[PythonAnywhere wiki: "why do I get a 403 forbidden error when opening a url?"](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/403ForbiddenError)

Answer (score 1):

I recently used urllib2 with a flask project on pythonanywhere using their free account to access an api at donorschoose.org

This might be helpful,

```
@app.route('/funding')
def fundingByState():
    urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'proxy.server:3128'})))
    donors_choose_url = "http://api.donorschoose.org/common/json_feed.html?historical=true&APIKey=DONORSCHOOSE"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(donors_choose_url)
    json_response = json.load(response)
    return json.dumps(json_response)
```

This does work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using paid account but still get this error message
try this [pythonanywhere_forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1677/)

To me, I have to delete the console then restart a new one.