# python: download a zip file but return error

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I want to download a zip file from a link. The link points to a zip file which I can download to local storage. Now I want to download it in pythonanywhere, which is a cloud python environment

However, it return error `zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`

```
import requests, zipfile, StringIO

r = requests.get('https://www.url', stream=True)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
z.extractall("/home/bybye/shinv")
```

How to download it successfully?

Comment: Obvious question: how do you know that the file at `www.url` is a zip file?

Comment: I download it into my PC manually

Comment: Could you add the output of `$ file www.url` ?

Comment: @malat where I should add `$ file www.url`?

Comment: From your terminal where you downloaded `www.url`

Comment: @malat I am not sure I understand correctly. The output is call `history.zip`. Is it what you want to know? perhaps you can show me if I am wrong

Comment: How do you know it is a zip file, and not some other kind of file?

Comment: @ScottHunter in this case, can I just download a file regardless the type? I have downloaded the file before but we can do a test. I just need it to be downloaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 3? If you are you need to replace StringIO with ByteIO

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get(zip_file_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall()
```

[Release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: I am in python 2.7

Comment: Can you try it with BytesIO instead of StringIO?

Comment: test it but return `zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`

Comment: the actual link is here but it require a login `https://www.shareinvestor.com/prices/price_download_zip_file.zip?type=history_daily&date=20170517&market=bursa`. I have login via selenium before the code above

Comment: Have you dropped the stream=True from your code? If you are streaming the file you'll need to iterate over the the response because it will be chunked.

Comment: i did drop the stream=True. I folllow exactly your code