# Getting Proxy error 'Name or service not found' when using PythonAnywhere server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, pythonanywhere

I am using Python3/flask. When I am trying to access a url it says 'Name or service not found'. But I am able to access the url when I try to do it using my local editor Pycharm. I know PythonAnywhere only allows whitelisted urls else it gives a 403 forbidden error. Here in my case I am getting 'service not found' error so it is not a case where PythonAnywhere is restricting the access. My code as follows (Cannot share the credentials because of security issues)

```
                line = 1

                try:
                    USERNAME = "******"
                    PASSWORD = "******"

                    URI = "https://jofa9908cdf9.hana.ondemand.com/ibass/IBASS_1/IOT_DASHBOARD/SERVICES/IOT_DASHBOARD.xsjs?CMD=equip_dev_health&IP_PLANT=1000&IP_PLANT=1"

                    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

                    proxies = {"http": "http://<username>:<password>@rb-proxy-apac.bosch.com:8080","https": "https://<username>:<password>@rb-proxy-apac.bosch.com:8080"}


                    CERT_FILE = False

                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError)

                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.ConnectionError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.PoolError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.HTTPWarning)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.SecurityWarning)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.SSLError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.ClosedPoolError)
                    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.RequestError)


                    line += 1#2

                    authed_session = requests.Session()

                    line += 1#3

                    authed_session.auth = (USERNAME, PASSWORD)

                    line += 1#4
                    authed_session.verify = CERT_FILE
                    authed_session.trust_env = CERT_FILE

                    line += 1#5

                    authed_session.headers.update({'User-Agent':USER_AGENT})

                    line += 1#6
                    fetched_data = authed_session.get(URI, proxies=proxies)

                    line += 1#7

                    line += 1#8
                    #print(fetched_data.text)
                    data = fetched_data.json()
                    return jsonify(str(data['EQUIP_ON']))

                    #soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fetched_data.text,'lxml')
                    #x = soup.select('content')
                    #x = soup.select('div')
                    #print(x)

                    #for i in x:
                    #   print(i.getText())
                    #  #print(i)

                except Exception as e:
                    #print(line)
                    #print(str(e))
                    return jsonify("at line number="+str(line)+" "+str(e))
```

I am getting an exception in line number 6. The exception is as follows- (I have a frontend. The image here is a screenshot from my frontend)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Comment: @Glenn In that issue it says Forbidden error. I hope you have some knowledge about networking and you can distinguish between 'Forbidden error' and 'Name or service not known error'. Please go through the entire text before down voting it.

Comment: You're specifying a proxy in your code; PythonAnywhere free accounts have to connect to the external Internet using a proxy that the system provides, so if you try to bypass it, the connection won't work.